# How to hide label and textfield if it is ' Yes ' but also fill in the gap with the label below?

Tags: swift, stack, label, dropdown, viewcontroller

I want to do something like in the gif..
So, if i click yes, I want the label disappeared but instead, i have to click the dropdown first to make it disappear.
and as well as pushing up the other label & text field.
How do i do that?

should I use stack or table view and put the table & dropdown inside them?
or should i just refresh the view controller on particular part of code?
i'm a bit confuse here.
because for now i just put it on the view controller space.

Thankyou in advance guys, appreciate it!

[image: Case]

Comment: Take  a vertical StackView. Take 4 horizontal stack view under vertical StackView. Put label and textfield in each horizontal StackView. Which label you want to hide. Hide that horizontal StackView.

Answer (score 1):

If you have fix number of data then you can use stackView and if you have dynamic data then you should use Tableview for it.
If you choose stackView then just hide (yourView.isHidden = true) the specific view that you want to hide and you will get your desired result.